# How to reference an injected grammar within a custom VSCode language

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, textmate, tmlanguage

Prefacing the below.  A demo project illustrating this issue can be found at:
https://github.com/kirksl/so60384141

I can reference an injected grammar within a native VSCode language

specifying this (package.json)

```
        "grammars": 
        [
            {
                "scopeName": "source.js.mylang",
                "path": "./syntaxes/mylang-js.tmLanguage.json",
                "injectTo": ["source.js"]
            }
        ]
```

and this (./syntaxes/mylang-js.tmLanguage.json)

```
{
  "scopeName": "source.js.mylang",
  "injectionSelector": "L:source",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "include": "#todo-keyword"
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "todo-keyword": {
      "match": "TODO",
      "name": "keyword.todo"
    }
  }
}
```

i'm seeing this (.js file, native JS)

[image]

So far so good.

However I can't seem to reference the same injected grammar within my custom language detailed below.  Fenced code blocks with triple quotes should utilize it.

Updating, now, this (package.json)

```
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": "mylang",
                "aliases": ["Mylang", "mylang"],
                "extensions": [".mylang"],
                "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
            }
        ],
        "grammars": 
        [
            {
                "language": "mylang",
                "scopeName": "source.mylang",
                "path": "./syntaxes/mylang.tmLanguage.json",
                "embeddedLanguages": {
                    "meta.embedded.block.javascript": "javascript"
                }
            },
            {
                "scopeName": "source.js.mylang",
                "path": "./syntaxes/mylang-js.tmLanguage.json",
                "injectTo": ["source.js"]
            }
        ]
```

and additionally specifying this (./syntaxes/mylang-js.tmLanguage.json)

```
    "fenced-expression": {
      "begin": "(^|\\G)\\s*[\"]{3}\\s*$",
      "end": "(^|\\G)\\s*[\"]{3}\\s*$",
      "contentName": "meta.embedded.block",
      "beginCaptures": {
        "0": {
          "name": "string.quoted.triple.mylang"
        }
      },
      "endCaptures": {
        "0": {
          "name": "string.quoted.triple.mylang"
        }
      },
      "patterns": [
        {
          "begin": "^(\\s*)(?=[\\S&&[^{<\\[]])",
          "while": "^(?!\\s*[\"]{3}\\s*)",
          "contentName": "meta.embedded.block.javascript",
          "patterns": [
            {
              "include": "source.js"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

i'm seeing this (.mylang file, JS highlighted, TODO not highlighted)

[image]

Finally just showing that some of the plumbing is there to enable the highlighting i'm looking for

if I switch `"include": "source.js"` to `"include": "source.js.mylang"`

```
    "fenced-expression": {
      "begin": "(^|\\G)\\s*[\"]{3}\\s*$",
      "end": "(^|\\G)\\s*[\"]{3}\\s*$",
      "contentName": "meta.embedded.block",
      "beginCaptures": {
        "0": {
          "name": "string.quoted.triple.mylang"
        }
      },
      "endCaptures": {
        "0": {
          "name": "string.quoted.triple.mylang"
        }
      },
      "patterns": [
        {
          "begin": "^(\\s*)(?=[\\S&&[^{<\\[]])",
          "while": "^(?!\\s*[\"]{3}\\s*)",
          "contentName": "meta.embedded.block.javascript",
          "patterns": [
            {
              "include": "source.js.mylang"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

i'm seeing this (.mylang file, JS not highlighted, TODO highlighted)

[image]

Comment: Hm, still not sure we have everything needed to reproduce. What does `mylang.tmLanguage.json` look like? You only show `mylang-js.tmLanguage.json`.

Comment: @Gama11 I've posted a demo project at https://github.com/kirksl/so60384141

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `"patterns":[{"include": "source.js.mylang"}]` to actually make use of the syntax highlighting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject `mylang-js.tmLanguage.json` into `source.mylang` as well (`injectTo` only applies to the top-level scope name, see explanation [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87496#issuecomment-576645129)):

```json
{
    "scopeName": "source.js.mylang",
    "path": "./syntaxes/mylang-js.tmLanguage.json",
    "injectTo": ["source.js", "source.mylang"]
}
```

Then it appears to work as intended:

[image]

Also, you will have to adjust your `injectionSelector` to make sure `TODO` highlighting is only applied within comments in embedded JS blocks:

```json
"injectionSelector": "L:comment.line.double-slash.js"
```

Comment: i added "source.mylang" as you recommended to "injectTo" and see TODO highlighted, but i'm seeing a problem.  if you remove "//" or use TODO outside of the fenced triple quotes where its not JS it's still highlighting TODO.  really hoping to extend only JS code with TODO highlighting.

Comment: Using the proper `injectionSelector` seems to solve both of those issues (see my updated answer).

Comment: Good point.  Oversight on my part.  Massive thank you for helping me solve this.  I owe you a beer or whatever beverage you subscribe to.  Curious with this setup is "embeddedLanguages" for "javascript" in the grammar even needed at this point?  Removing it makes no difference.

Comment: Good question. It seems to be necessary for editor features apart from syntax highlighting to work correctly within the embedded language, such as "toggle line comment", see also: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34598